# Fan problem on ThinkPad T440s. Works ACPI?

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, fan

I have still problem with fan on my ThinkPad T440s. I spent lot of time with googling and trying diferent configurations but my problem is still persit...

My thinkfan service probably service works:

```
sudo service thinkfan status 

● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-16 17:17:01 CET; 1 day 14h ago
 Main PID: 31374 (thinkfan)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/thinkfan.service
           └─31374 /usr/sbin/thinkfan

jan 16 17:17:01 T440s systemd[1]: Starting simple and lightweight fan control program...
jan 16 17:17:01 T440s thinkfan[31373]: thinkfan 0.9.1 starting...
jan 16 17:17:01 T440s thinkfan[31373]: Daemon PID: 31374
jan 16 17:17:01 T440s systemd[1]: Started simple and lightweight fan control program.
```

But after few minutes after restart OS is my fan so loud and run with full speed:

```
cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan

status:     disabled
speed:      65535
level:      0
commands:   level <level> (<level> is 0-7, auto, disengaged, full-speed)
commands:   enable, disable
commands:   watchdog <timeout> (<timeout> is 0 (off), 1-120 (seconds))
```

Speed of my fan everytime 65535 (without any changes).

Temperatures on my Thinkpad are fine:

```
sensors

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        65535 RPM

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +30.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

But when i try command: dstat --cpufreq --fan --thermal i see "curious" error:

**Module dstat_thermal failed to load. (Needs kernel ACPI or IBM-ACPI support)**

```
dstat --cpufreq --fan --thermal    

Module dstat_thermal failed to load. (Needs kernel ACPI or IBM-ACPI support)

-----frequency----- fan-
cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3|spee
   0    0    0    0|  65
  42   42   42   42|  65
  42   42   42   42|  65
  42   42   42   42|  65
  42   42   42   42|  65
  42   42   42   42|  65
```

In files: `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf` (i don't know which file i have to use, because in tutorials and topics on internet are used both files).

```
options thinkpad_acpi experimental=1 fan_control=1
```

**Bios was updated to latest version 2.50.**

**I tried it with kernels 4.20.0 and 4.15.**

Please, have you any ideas what i can do? Or is a HW fan problem?
I am still linux HW beginner and i don't knowledge to solve it :/

Thanks for any ideas.

**UPDATE**

New information (i don't know if is relevant):

```
sudo service fancontrol status
● fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-16 17:16:53 CET; 1 day 15h ago
     Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
           man:pwmconfig(8)

jan 16 17:16:53 T440s systemd[1]: Starting fan speed regulator...
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s fancontrol[31320]: Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s fancontrol[31320]: Common settings:
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s fancontrol[31320]:   INTERVAL=10
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s fancontrol[31320]: Error in configuration file:
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s fancontrol[31320]: FCTEMPS value is improperly formatted
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jan 16 17:16:53 T440s systemd[1]: Failed to start fan speed regulator.
```

And when i use command pwmconfig:

```
sudo pwmconfig
...
...
Testing pwm control hwmon2/pwm1 ...
  hwmon2/fan1_input ... speed was 65535 now 65535
    no correlation

No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon2/pwm1,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
```

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, probably it was HW problem with my fan. When i changed device to T450s everything works fine with default configurations.